# Cd 'ing to a directory by reading the argument for 'cd' from a file

Tags: shell, unix, cd

I've written a script to change directory (cd) by reading the value for cd from a file. But when I run this script I run into "No such file or directory" error.

This is the script I've written:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line  
do
IN=$line
set -- "$IN"
IFS=":"; declare -a Array=($*)
echo "File location : ${Array[1]}"
location=${Array[1]}
echo "Location : $location"
cd "$location"
echo "Pwd :"
pwd
done < location.properties
```

Contents of location.properties file:

```
A:~/Downloads
```

Output:

```
File location : ~/Downloads  
Location : ~/Downloads  
./script.sh: line 10: cd: ~/Downloads: No such file or directory  
Pwd :  
/home/path/to/current/dir
```

Both the echo statements print the location correctly but cd to it fails.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Tilde expansion only applies when '~' is unquoted." http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.22.2BAH4.22

Comment: BTW -- `Array=( $* )` is very broken. You probably want `Array=( "$@" )` if you want to preserve arguments with quoted/escaped spaces, wildcards, etc. That's _if_ you have any reason to copy the contents into a separate array at all, which I don't see here.

Comment: By the way -- what's your shell? I've been assuming a POSIX-compliant ksh derivative, but if it's something non-POSIX like zsh, that might change things.

Comment: If you want to split your line into an array on colons, the right way to do that is: `IFS=: read -r -a Array <<<"$line"`. None of this mess with `set --` and `$*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` isn't expanded by quotes. I generally suggest considering it an interactive feature only, and unavailable in scripts -- as the side effects from unquoted expansions in scripts aren't worth that particular benefit.

To perform this expansion step yourself:

```
if [[ $location = "~/"* || $location = "~" ]]; then
  location=$HOME/${location#"~"}
elif [[ $location = "~"?* ]]; then
  user=${location%%/*}
  user=${user#"~"}
  read _ _ _ _ _ home _ < <(getent passwd "$user")
  location="$home/${location#*/}"
fi
```

Of course, this is overkill, and the usual practice is to assume that scripts won't handle paths containing `~` if not expanded before their invocation (as by a calling shell).

Comment: +1 for expansion of ~user, and for remarking on the overkill!

Comment: I used this but I still get the same error. Error : script.sh: line 21: cd: $HOME/Downloads: No such file or directory

Comment: @Malick ...so. That means that `$HOME` was emitted unexpanded. The exact code I gave here doesn't do that. Did you perhaps use single quotes around `'$HOME'`? It's actually important that it be either unquoted (which is safe only because it's part of an assignment) or double-quoted.

Comment: @Malick, ...also, if this is running via a cron daemon, an at daemon, or something which otherwise doesn't get a full compliment of environment variables, make sure it has a HOME. That said, that bug *wouldn't* cause the issue you describe here, as it would just lead to the value expanding to nothing at all (and being `/Downloads`).

Comment: @Malick: I've tested this locally, **exactly** as given, and I properly get `/home/myusername//Downloads`. A bit excessive re: the slashes, but perfectly workable.

Comment: @Charles : I have not used single quote around $HOME, have used the same code you provided. I also tried using double quotes but didn't help. I'm not sure why it's giving the same error. It's not a cron too.

Comment: @Malick, see the code running successfully on a 3rd-party-controlled machine at http://ideone.com/abvefO. If you can give me an example that fails (by putting a literal `$HOME` into the result string), either on that site or as code I can run myself, I'd be appreciative.

Comment: @Charles: I have deadlines to meet and since you also it's a overkill, I'm thinking of dropping the '~'. I replaced it with $HOME variable's value in the property file and it seems to work fine. Your time and effort is highly appreciated. I'll accept your answer since it helped me understand certain things. Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

either remove the quotes around $location (as suggested by other comments already) or, if you need the quotes for some reason, prefix the command with "eval" like:
eval cd "$location"
I have just tried the eval method (with quotes around ~) and it works.

Comment: The eval method will break in the same way, and in the same places, as just-removing-the-quotes does. Try doing this with filenames containing spaces.

Comment: ...also, see BashFAQ #48 re risks associated with `eval`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048